# JOIN Products that are IN another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to join some Products based on if they're in a table or not. I'm using MSSQL and I'm  trying to do this to see if the category has some products.

simplified Query:

```
SELECT c.CategoryID, c.Name, p.ProductID
FROM Category AS c
JOIN Product AS p ON p.ProductID IN (
   SELECT PrductID FROM exampleTable
)
```

ProductTable:

| ProductID | CategoryID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |

The output I receive:

| CategoryID | Name | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat1 | 1 |
| 1 | Cat1 | 2 |
| 2 | Cat2 | 3 |
| 4 | Cat4 | 4 |

The expected output:

| CategoryID | Name | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat1 | 1 |
| 2 | Cat2 | 3 |
| 4 | Cat4 | 4 |

I'm trying to only join a product if it's in the select statement and not join all products which have the same category id.

In pseudo code I'm trying to achive this:

```
JOIN Product AS p IF p.ProductID IN (Subquery)
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed banga's answer is IMHO more elegant and perfoment but to be closer to what you proposed in your question, you can simply use a `where` clause.

```
SELECT c.CategoryID, c.Name, p.ProductID
FROM Category AS c
JOIN Product AS p ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
WHERE p.ProductID IN (
   SELECT PrductID FROM exampleTable
)
```

Comment: @forpas You are right. I was just focused on the where clause